# World of Warcraft Basic LUA Scripting

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm new to LUA scripting and need help with a starting point. I'd like to place a small red box under my character avatar, when I'm in combat. Can anyone help out or point me to a "Basics" site?

Comment: Simple things like that can be done with WeakAuras, which also supports LUA scripts, but without the requirement of scripting your own UI elements. Or if you really want to look into addon development you can start [here](https://wowwiki.fandom.com/wiki/AddOn_programming_tutorial/Introduction).